# JPA em.find(id) works on Oracle but not on MariaDB

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

Hello I have an application which runs on JBoss EAP 7 with JPA Hibernate.

I have problems with a simple `entityManager.find(id)` call.

The call produces against an Oracle 12 database one SQL

```
select messagedat0_.id as id1_4_0_,
       messagedat0_.messageid as messageid3_4_0_, 
       messagedat0_.messageblob as messageblob2_4_0_, 
       messagedat0_.messagetype as messagetype4_4_0_, 
       messagedat0_.retaintime as retaintime5_4_0_, 
       extractedv1_.messageid as messageid1_1_1_, 
       extractedv1_.absender as absender2_1_1_, 
       extractedv1_.empfaenger as empfaenger3_1_1_,
       extractedv1_.nachrichtentyp as nachrichtentyp4_1_1_, 
       extractedv1_.uuid as uuid5_1_1_ 
from messagedata messagedat0_
left outer join ExtractedValues extractedv1_ on messagedat0_.messageid=extractedv1_.messageid
where messagedat0_.id=?
```

which returns the entity.

Against a MariaDB it produces TWO SELECTS
Hibernate:

```
select messagedat0_.id as id1_4_0_,
       messagedat0_.messageid as messagei3_4_0_,
       messagedat0_.messageblob as messageb2_4_0_,
       messagedat0_.messagetype as messaget4_4_0_,
       messagedat0_.retaintime as retainti5_4_0_,
       extractedv1_.messageid as messagei1_1_1_,
       extractedv1_.absender as absender2_1_1_,
       extractedv1_.empfaenger as empfaeng3_1_1_,
       extractedv1_.nachrichtentyp as nachrich4_1_1_,
       extractedv1_.uuid as uuid5_1_1_
from messagedata messagedat0_
left outer join ExtractedValues extractedv1_ on messagedat0_.messageid=extractedv1_.messageid
where messagedat0_.id=?

2018-11-22 09:46:36,328 INFO  [stdout] (default task-26) Hibernate:
select extractedv0_.messageid as messagei1_1_0_,
       extractedv0_.absender as absender2_1_0_,
       extractedv0_.empfaenger as empfaeng3_1_0_,
       extractedv0_.nachrichtentyp as nachrich4_1_0_,
       extractedv0_.uuid as uuid5_1_0_
from ExtractedValues extractedv0_ where extractedv0_.messageid=?
```

When I run the two selects manually the first Select does return a row the second not.
This causes the find Method to return NULL. Which is not the expected result in my opinion.

from the 
**Messagedata Entity:**

```
@Id
private String id;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="messageid", referencedColumnName="messageid", updatable=false)
private Set<Msginformation> msginformations;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="messageid", referencedColumnName="messageid")
private Set<Protocol> protocols;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="messageid", referencedColumnName="messageid")
private Set<Retry> retries;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="messageid", referencedColumnName="messageid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private ExtractedValues extractedValues;
```

The OneToOne Relationship to ExtractedValues causes the problems on MariaDB.
I have tried to set

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
```

in persistence.xml, but this does not solve the problem.
I have no idea what to do about this…

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use either of the below dialects :

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
```

or

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwers.

Comment: Please accept the answer if the solution provided worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not passing proper dialect. Please check the dialect.

You can use below dialect.

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers
I have tried both dialects with

```
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect"/>
```

Unfortunetly JBoss then refuses to deploy the war

Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]